# How to use ngModules defined in app.module.ts for lazy loaded component?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

My goal is to lazy load the app. **I want to only import the NgModules once, in `app.module.ts`**

For example `user.component.ts` needs the `FormsModule` and the `HttpClientModule`. I want to import the NgModules in `app.module.ts` instead of `components/user/user.module.ts`

Currently, if `user.component.ts` needs the `FormsModule` and `HttpClientModule`, I need to import it in `user.module.ts`. In theory, I will need to import `HttpClientModule` for every `View` that use `HttpClient.get()`. **I am worried this will increase the bundle size for `lazy loaded component`.**

This is the example `app.module.ts` that I want to achieve.

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpClientModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

=== `tl:dr` down below is the current solution I use `use user.module.ts` and import the `HttpClientModule` for every View that use `HttpClient.get()`

app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

app-routing.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    loadChildren: () => import('./components/user/user.module').then(m => m.UserModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'about/:id',
    loadChildren: () => import('./components/about/about.module').then(m => m.AboutModule),
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

components/user/user.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

import { UserRoutingModule } from './user-routing.module';
import { UserComponent } from './user.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    UserRoutingModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpClientModule
  ],
  declarations: [UserComponent]
})
export class UserModule { }
```

Comment: you can awlays build your app for production and check if your bundle size is actually getting bigger or not